# Racket combinations function

Tags: scheme, racket

I need some explanation on how the following code for computing combinations of a list works.

```
(define combs L k)
  (cond ((= 0 k)
         '(()))
        ((null? L)
         '())
        (else
         (append (map (λ (x) (cons (car L) x)) 
                          (combs (cdr L) (- k 1)))
                 (combs (cdr L) k))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Combining zero elements from a list gives `'(())`.
- Combining anything from an empty list give `'()`.
- For the final case, the result has two parts:

  1. The combinations that contain `(car L)`, and
  2. The combinations that don't.

The answer for item 2 is to just make combinations of `k` elements from `(cdr L)`.
For item 1, form the combinations of `k - 1` elements from `(cdr L)`, and then add `(car L)` to each one.